# SAS graph behaving differently

Tags: graph, plot, sas

For some reason the graph is behaving differently for the firs two data points even though the data looks perfectly fine. In the following graph the mean value for the first two points 3 and 6 are not coming out as the data for those two groups.

The data looks absolutely fine and the graph should come out as per the data. I am unable to figure out why it is behaving that way.

Could anyone figure that out.

I would highly appreciate your help.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The upper error bars for the first 2 points are not displayed because they exceed the 1.2 upper limit for the plot.

Try enhancing it a little bit.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Sometimes those small things boggles mind. :)

Comment: user3521567 - welcome to SO.  Remember to hit 'accept' if you find an answer to your question..  A small token of appreciation for @DaBigNikoladze's time!